# How to add multiple language support in Delphi XE2 application

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, multiple-languages

I'm a beginner in Delphi but I need to add multiple other languages support to current application.

Projects->Languages->Add(languages) does not work in my version of Delphi and gives these errors on compiling:

```
[Error] E1026 File not found: 'vcl\DBLOGDLG.dfm'
[Error] E1026 File not found: 'vcl\DBPWDLG.dfm'
```

I tried creating my own translation by adding them to [root]/lang/ en.rc , lt.rc, lv.rc
Example of lang.rc

```
STRINGTABLE
BEGIN
    telefon_monitor L"Phone Monitoring"
    koned L"Calls"
    alates L"From"
    kuni L"Until"
    vali_numbrid L"Choose numbers"
    otsi L"Search"
    tolgi L"Translate"
    satted L"Settings"
    salvesta L"Save"
    lisa_rida L"Add row"
END
```

I have no idea how to read them.

**Does anyone have any better idea how to load translations?**
What I want to do is, read config.ini [language] section and based that display translation from .rc file or some better extensions.

Comment: This part of the version of Delphi you are using doesn't like paths with spaces in them.  See: https://www.codenewsfast.com/cnf/thread/0/permalink.thr-ng1883q145

Comment: You could try to use a fast VCL compoent called TLanguages, you can find it on github! https://github.com/albertodev01/TLanguages

Comment: @Brian I saw that too, but no help. After removing spaces I get other error. But it does not matter. Alberto Miola posted TLanguages seems good and not stale. Thank you both of you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Could not use github.com/albertodev01/TLanguages on Delphi XE2 which sucks.

I ended up creating a **translation.json** file and overwrite default values on **Application.FormCreate** plus made language toggle system

```
{ "en_EN":{ "hello":"Hello!" },
  "lv_LT":{ "hello":"Hi!" }
}
```

PS! Parsing nested json in older Delphi is something else.

Comment: you can consider putting the code in translation in Form.Activate and not in Form.Create.

Comment: also, you are on the right track. save the translation in your database so that if you make a web version of your application, you can re-use it. same logic